# If I want to create multiple forms, possible to have one main in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, program-entry-point

If I want to have multiple forms in an appication, can I do it with only 
one main? I am working with Visual Studio C# (Windows Application).

Thank you.

Comment: When you have all your forms as described in the answers you can even get to them with the [Application.OpenForms property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  There is nothing preventing you from having multiple `Form` instances in a .Net application with only a single thread / main method.

```
var f1 = new Form();
f1.Show();
var f2 = new Form();
f2.Show();
```

Depending on how you want these forms to be related though there are some subtle changes you may want to make to the startup code.  Can you give us a bit more information on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to make a video game and I want to do 
some introductions before starting the game. Also, by "var"
above do you mean the type? 
Thank you.

Comment: @George, `var` is used for type inference in C#.  You can just replace it with the type of the `Form`

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.  You can say `new Form()` all day long.

Comment: You would have to tell the `new Form()` to be `Visible = true` to have it pop up on your screen, or `ShowDialog(parentForm)` to make it modal.

Answer (score 0):

They're right, but if you want to edit the form in the designer first use **Project** -> **Add Windows Form** and select a name for the form.

This will add another form to the project and let you can open and edit it in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use form inheritance if you want a common form design.

Answer (score -2):

var f1 = new Form(); 
here var is variant datatype in .NET 3.5 which basically object type that can store any objects in it.

Comment: -1 var is not a variant datatype .. it indicates that the compiler should infer the type from the initialization expression